# Ember computed property is not summing array of numbers

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a [js.bin](http://jsbin.com/AzOgUgAS/1/edit?html,js,output) where I am attempting to display the sum of all winnings attributes within my Fixture data.  My computed property `sumOfWinnings` does this on page render, except when I create a new record it breaks.  Here is my computed property:

```
sumOfWinnings: function(){
  var array = this.filter(function(round){
    return round.get('winnings') > 0;
  });
  //sum(); is a declared function, adding elements within an array
  return this.sum(array.mapProperty('winnings'));
}.property('@each')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The part that i see breaking is the summing.  The input field is a string, so you need to parse it at some point

```
    add: function(){
      var winnings = this.get('winnings');
      var round = this.store.createRecord('round',{
        winnings: parseInt(winnings)
      });
      round.save();
      this.set('winnings','');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I overlooked that.